# Low Maximum execution time

Tags: installation, 7

I was installing drupal commons on xampp server i got this error, PHP Max Execution Time 30 Your PHP execution time is too low, please set it greater than or equal to 120 seconds. How do i adjust the php execution time so that i can proceed with the installation?

Comment: make change in php.ini file. Search max_execution_time and set to 120

Comment: Adding to @Smalution comment, you should restart your server once you done changes in php.ini

Answer (score 1):

Follow  below steps and change that file.

1. Go to your XAMPP installation Folder and edit - ..\xampp\php\php.ini file.
2. Use the FIND function of your editor an look for "max_execution_time"
3. in that line you will see the value attributed to "max_execution_time"
   change it to **max_execution_time=120**
4. Save the php.ini file.
5. Restart the XAMPP Server
6. Proceed with Drupal Commons installation.